# Как запустить .exe находящися в ресурсах jar?

Tags: java

Добрый вечер, есть не большая программа которую я могу запустить с помощью своего java кода данной конструкцией

```
Runtime r = Runtime. getRuntime();
    Process p = null;
    String cmd[] = {"адрес программы"};
    try {p = r.exec(cmd);}
    catch (Exception ee) {}
```

но адрес программы может поменяться. Возникла идея поместить эту программу в папку проекта, и вызывать оттуда когда запускаешь jar но как это реализовать в коде ?

Comment: точно так же запускать java -jar X.jar MainClass, указывая адрес текущего jar

Comment: @Etki вы так имели ввиду "java -jar Ton.jar Main -o src/resources/sp/Sp.exe" ?

Comment: не, экзешник не получится, экзшник придется распаковывать во внешнюю систему

Comment: @Etki как его распаковку реализовать в коде ?

Comment: getClass().getResourceAsStream() и этот стрим куда угодно сохраняете

Comment: @Etki так этот метод его только читает при использование данной конструкции Main.class.getResourceAsStream(path); создался файл в корне папки проекта Ton.iml это что ?

Comment: ...и куда угодно его сохраняете